# Calculate Average in php eliminating those data which screw up all average

Tags: php

I want to calculate average of time spent on each task

But while calculating the average i dont want to count those time for average which is taking very long amount of time.

Lets say we have **5 task**:

**Task 1** takes **500** seconds
**Task 2** takes **300** seconds
**Task 3** takes **4000** seconds
**Task 4** takes **450** seconds
**Task 5** takes **500** seconds

If we calculate the **average** the result will be **1150** seconds.

But i want to eliminate those data from average calculation due to which the average is screwed up (4000 in this example). The reason for this is it may be possible that we don't have enough resource to complete the task at that time and taking longer because we are waiting for that resource.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or written any code?

Comment: By the way they're called outliers

Comment: Yes i have tried some code but it gives me average of all time. i want to eliminate the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each task and only add its time value to the total count for averaging if it is less than whatever your preferred maximum would be. Use the counter you use for the loop and set another counter to count when one gets skipped. The divider would be the total count minus the second counter.

Comment: The maximum time is not fixed. It may be 2 days or 5 days.
Maximum time depends on the time taken by other task.
Lets say: If some task are taking 3 days to complete and other 3 task are taking 8 days, then i don't want those 8 days to calculate average.

Or,

If some task A,B,C and E are taking 40 Minutes to complete and task D and F are taking 5 hours, then i don't want task D and F to come in story for average.

Comment: If you put all the values into an array you might be able to use something from this to compare the values: http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php or perhaps sort the array and walk through it until you find a value that is greater than n% bigger than the smallest. Then take only those prior to that one to use in your average.